# Dart Keyboard Event Command Line

Tags: dart, flutter, keyboard-events

I've been monkeying around with Dart (& Flutter more specifically on mobile) and have become quite interested in trying Flutter on Desktop.

Anyways, for this one app idea, I need the ability to create a key event. From my research, I found this: https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-html/KeyEvent-class.html which mentions a `KeyEvent` however this primarily relates to Dart:HTML (which I presume just means browser only).

Does Dart run in the command line support any ability for generating key events? Like say I wanted an app to type something for a user.

Thanks!

Comment: Bit of a late reply, but came across this as I started looking for the same thing. I have similarly found nothing particularly useful. The best solution I have found thus far is to set `stdin.echoMode` and `stdin.lineMode` to false and then add a listener to stdin. I created an issue [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/37591) if you are still interested.

Answer (score 0):

@Isaac has basically explained it in his comment but this is how it looks like in code:

```
import 'dart:io';

void main(){
  stdin.echoMode = false;
  stdin.lineMode = false;

  while(true){
    if(stdin.readByteSync() == 102){  // f
      print('You payed respect');
    }
    else{break;}
  }
}
```